# Openshift oc params-file format

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I want to provide a different set of parameters to an openshift template depending on the specific deployment. I have been using

```
oc new-app -f my-template.yml -p P1="p1-override-value" -p P2="p2-override-value" ...
```

However, the list of parameter overrides on the command line is getting very long and unwieldy. The oc CLI has an option available, "--param-file=" that presumably solves my problem, but nowhere can I find what the expected yaml (or JSON) format should be. Can someone that has used param-files in openshift provide a sample param-file please?

Comment: My first guess would be that it is neither JSON or YAML, but a list, one per line, of ``A=B`` values.

Comment: The parameter is mentioned in the OC document [https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/applications/application_life_cycle_management/creating-applications-using-cli.html](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/applications/application_life_cycle_management/creating-applications-using-cli.html). The file format will match that of an .env file (for environment variables).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its very simple. 
Create a file say test.env and have a key value pairs for your parameters. 
Ex:

```
BUILD_IMAGE_PREFIX=test.xyz.com:5000
BUILD_IMAGE_TAG=:latest
```

In your teamplate.yaml file externalize the values you want to use from env file. 
Ex: 
image: `${BUILD_IMAGE_PREFIX}/abc${BUILD_IMAGE_TAG}`

Now, deploy the dc in openshift using below command:

`oc process --param-file=test.env -f test.yaml | oc create -f -`

Comment: How does this work for multi-line values?

Comment: @Michiel and whomever is still wondering about the (possible) format(s) for files specified with the `--param-file` argument -- judging from [the current (at the moment of writing this) source code](https://github.com/openshift/oc/blob/27327b8ffa98c990b4977d9508c8df2fa488601f/pkg/helpers/newapp/app/env.go#L220-L253) of `oc process ...`, the parsing procedure is on the more crude and simple side, suggesting simple key-value format (comments and quoting allowed) ala "environment file", and multi-line doesn't seem to be supported, at least not as far as I could assess.